# Hiding one button out of three buttons using iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

I've a UITableView with around 5 cells (rows). Each cell(row) has three UIButtons added as the respective cell's subview.

**Row1:** Button1    Button2     Button3 // all these buttons has tag = row_number = 1

**Row2:** Button1    Button2     Button3 // all these buttons has tag = row_number = 2

**Row3:** Button1    Button2     Button3 // all these buttons has tag = row_number = 3

**Row4:** Button1    Button2     Button3 // all these buttons has tag = row_number = 4

**NOTE:** 
Buttons1 of all the rows are connected to the same IBAction.
Similarly,
Buttons2 of all the rows are connected to the same IBAction. so on...
I'm perfectly able to detect which button has been pressed within a cell. I'm using tags for this.

**I want to do the following:**

1. If a button is pressed from a row, it should hide on press while all other buttons in the same row should remain displayed. After some time, if another button is pressed from the same row then the newly pressed button should hide while the previously hidden button should be brought back to the view.

Currently I'm able to hide the first button pressed, but cannot bring it back if the other button from the same row is pressed afterwards.

2. Is this also possible to keep track of the previously pressed buttons WITHIN THE SAME ROW?

Please guide me how should I implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is many ways to around this. One solution could be to subclass `UITableViewCell` and make your own implementation in there. It will be easier for you to control the contents of each cell.

Answer (score 0):

As your problem only affects a single cell at once, we can focus on a cell.

You should use a `UITableViewCell` subclass that keeps references to it's buttons and is the `target` for their actions.

Thus the subclass can manage all view-related interface changes nicely encapsulated.

You may then use [Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) to propagate the actions to your view controller and handle the actual logic.

**Edit**

As to your second question, with this setup, it is easy to keep track of the order of button presses within the cell by appending each button's index to an `[Int]` on each press.

Comment: Perfect, thanks everyone for the answers. Meanwhile I've also found out the solution to problem#1 by creating global arrays for the buttons and then within each IBAction I've set the other buttons' hidden property to FALSE.

Comment: that is a horrible sollution from a archetectual, OOP point of view. Think *seperation of concerns* and *encapsulation*.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
 {
  let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell



  // add a line for each one of the buttons
   cell.btn1.addTarget(self, action: "handleButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
   cell.btn2.addTarget(self, action: "handleButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
   cell.btn3.addTarget(self, action: "handleButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
   cell.btn4.addTarget(self, action: "handleButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)


   return cell
  }

   @IBAction func handleButtonPressed(sender:UIButton!)
 {

 switch sender.tag {

   let button = sender as! UIButton
   let view = button.superview!
   let cell = view.superview as! custom cell
  // cell.btn1  - will get here 
  //cell.btn2 - will get here
  // do based on what on button action hide or show
  case 0:
  print(sender.tag)

  case 1:
  print(sender.tag)
  case 2:
  print(sender.tag)
  case 3:
  print(sender.tag)

    default:
    print("Tag was not found")
   }
 }
```